# Java: Convert a string to an existing final object

Tags: java, string, logging

Is it possible to convert a Java String to a final Java Object.

Lets take a example:

In a .properties file I have the following statement

```
log_level=Level.ALL
```

Now, `Level.ALL` is a final object of Level.

What I want to do in the code is to read the .properties file, read the log_level as a String and `<somehow magically>` parse the String into the object `Level.ALL`.

Comment: Well, I'm not understanding your question completely... First, a final variable is one which after assignment cannot be changed, doesn't mean that the content cannot be changed (well, on String it does mean that because String objects cannot be changed). Now, a final static class variable is a constant and is written as that at compile time, there you cannot change anything at runtime. What shouldn't be confused is that the "final" modifier qualifies the variable, not the object per se. What is it what you want to achieve? Do you have some code sample?

Answer (score 2):

Store only "ALL", and then use `Level.parse(stringFromConfig)` -  and you get the final object Level.ALL.

---

To satisfy your hunger for exact answer, I wrote the following code.
I'm not entirely sure this is what you meant, but it's the best I could think of.

As you can see in the crazy `catch` jungle, it's a dangerous stuff we're dealing with.

```
String str = "Level.SEVERE";

String pcg = Level.class.getPackage().getName();

str = pcg + "." + str;

// now we have package.ClassName.fieldName in "str"

String className = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.'));
String fieldName = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, str.length());

try {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName(className);

    Field f = c.getDeclaredField(fieldName);

    // here comes content of the field
    // for non-final fields you must put field's class here instead of NULL
    Object o = f.get(null); 

    System.out.println(o);

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Ha Ha... You did solve my problem, but didn't answer the question ;-)... Anyways, Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess you could achieve your goal with some crazy reflection code, but it sounds like shooting birds with a cannon. This is a more elegant solution, imo.

Comment: Here you go, I actually made some code for you. What I wouldn't do to get points for accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (System.getProperty("STANDALONE_LOG_LEVEL")!=null){
                    String logLevel= System.getProperty("STANDALONE_LOG_LEVEL");
                    switch(logLevel){

                    case "ERROR" :  this.aRootLogLevel=Level.ERROR;
                                    break;
                    case "DEBUG" :  this.aRootLogLevel=Level.DEBUG;
                                    break;
                    case "INFO" :   this.aRootLogLevel=Level.INFO;
                                    break;
                    case "WARN" :   this.aRootLogLevel=Level.WARN;
                                    break;
                    case "FATAL" :  this.aRootLogLevel=Level.FATAL;
                                    break;
                    default :       this.aRootLogLevel=Level.INFO;
                   }
            }
 rootLogger.setLevel( this.aRootLogLevel );
```